# Error con herencia en Java POO Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code

Tags: java, poo, herencia

lo que pasa es que estamos aprendiendo el tema de herencia y nos mandaron un ejercicio sencillo, que trata de agregar a una persona y luego listar las personas agregadas, la parte de agregar persona me sale bien, el problema es al listar las personas agregadas, a continuación les mostrare el condigo de la clase padre y la clase hija, y el código para listar clases.(Debo aclarar que la parte del Main tambien esta bien hecha. Muchas Gracias a todos.[image: SuperClase]

[image: ClaseHija][image: Llamado a Listar][image: Error al llamado a listar personas o estudiantes]

Comment: Por favor, no publiques código en imágenes. Pega directamente el código en la pregunta. Por otro lado, te recomiendo leer como crear un [mcve]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

El error es al instanciar el estudiante.
En el contructor de estudiante recibes dos strings (**`cedula y nombre`**) que luego los pasa a la superclase. 
Al instanciar un nuevo estudiante en tu clase **`ManejoEstudiante.java`** en la línea 69 deberías hacerlo asi:

```
Estudiante q = new Estudiante( "123456789", "Juan Perez");
```